# Opaleye query by String to Maybe

Tags: haskell, opaleye

I want to run a query against my table for a given value, and return a `Maybe a` depending on whether a row was found.

I have this domain:

```
data User' a b c d e f = User {  usrId :: a,
                                     usrApproved :: b,
                                     usrIden :: c, 
                                     usrImgUrl :: d,
                                     usrTitle :: e, 
                                     usrUrl :: f 
                                  }

type User = User' Int Bool String String String String

$(makeAdaptorAndInstance "pUser" ''User')

type UserColumn = User' (Column PGInt4) (Column PGBool) (Column PGText) (Column PGText) (Column PGText) (Column PGText)
```

and the following definitions for the table and queries:

```
userTable :: Table UserColumn UserColumn
userTable = Table "user" (pUser User {  usrId       = required "id",
                                                usrApproved = required "approved",
                                                usrIden     = required "identifier",
                                                usrImgUrl   = required "img_url",
                                                usrTitle    = required "title",
                                                usrUrl      = required "url"
                                             })

userQuery :: Query UserColumn
userQuery = queryTable userTable
```

As hinted previously, I want to query by the "identifier" column, so I've written this query and wish to return a `IO (Maybe User)

```
userByIdenQuery :: (Column PGText) -> Query UserColumn
userByIdenQuery iden = proc () -> do
  user <- userQuery -< ()
  restrict -< (adIden user) .=== iden
  returnA -< user    

getUserByIden :: String -> PGS.Connection -> IO (Maybe User)
getUserByIden iden c = do
  usr <- runQuery c (userByIdenQuery $ pgString iden)
  -- But this fails to compile
  undefined -- just to minimise compilation errors
```

this fails to compile with:

```
No instance for (Default
                   Opaleye.Internal.RunQuery.QueryRunner UserColumn haskells0)
  arising from a use of `runQuery'
The type variable `haskells0' is ambiguous
Note: there is a potential instance available:
  instance (product-profunctors-0.7.1.0:Data.Profunctor.Product.Class.ProductProfunctor
              p,
            Default p a1_0 a1_1, Default p a2_0 a2_1, Default p a3_0 a3_1,
            Default p a4_0 a4_1, Default p a5_0 a5_1, Default p a6_0 a6_1) =>
           Default
             p
             (User' a1_0 a2_0 a3_0 a4_0 a5_0 a6_0)
             (User' a1_1 a2_1 a3_1 a4_1 a5_1 a6_1)
    -- Defined at src\DB.hs:33:3
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  usr <- runQuery c (userByIdenQuery $ pgString iden)
In the expression:
  do { usr <- runQuery c (userByIdenQuery $ pgString iden);
       undefined }
In an equation for `getUserByIden':
    getUserByIden iden c
      = do { usr <- runQuery c (userByIdenQuery $ pgString iden);
             undefined }
```

If I try to implement the function:

```
getUserByIden :: String -> PGS.Connection -> IO (Maybe User)
getUserByIden iden c = do
  (usrId, appr, idn, imUrl, tit, url) <- runQuery c (userByIdenQuery $ pgString iden)
  return $ Just $ User usrId appr idn imUrl tit url
```

Then I'm presented with this compilation error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[haskells0]'
        with actual type `(Int, Bool, String, String, String, String)'
In the pattern: (usrId, appr, idn, imUrl, tit, url)
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  (usrId, appr, idn, imUrl, tit, url) <- runQuery
                                          c (userByIdenQuery $ pgString iden)
In the expression:
  do { (usrId, appr, idn, imUrl, tit, url) <- runQuery
                                               c (userByIdenQuery $ pgString iden);
       return $ Just $ User usrId appr idn imUrl tit url }

I really have no idea where to go with this, other than using a library other than Opaleye.
```

Comment: `runQuery` has a very general return type - give it a type signature, or the return value a type signature. The [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye-0.5.0.0/docs/Opaleye-RunQuery.html) very clearly state: "runQuery's use of the Default typeclass means that the compiler will have trouble inferring types. It is strongly recommended that you provide full type signatures when using runQuery."

Comment: How do I provide the type signature exactly? The haddock always confused me there.

Comment: In a sense, you have given it a type signature already - `getUserByIden :: String -> PGS.Connection -> IO (Maybe User)` - but `usr` is unused in the body so it cannot unify with `User`. If you actually implement the function, it may be sufficient. In the meantime you can write a type signature in any number of ways: `(x :: X) <- a` or `x <- a :: IO X` or `_x <- a; let x :: X; x = _x`

Comment: @atc Did you find a satisfactory solution to this?  If not feel free to ask me directly by [filing an issue](https://github.com/tomjaguarpaw/haskell-opaleye/issues) or by [emailing me](http://web.jaguarpaw.co.uk/%7Etom/contact/).

Comment: Thanks Tom, I did. The accepted answer was spot-on. Would've been nice to have this covered in the tutorial but that's me being pedantic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with OpalEye, but I think you might just need a judicious use of `listToMaybe` (`import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)`)

```
getUserByIden :: String -> PGS.Connection -> IO (Maybe User)
getUserByIden iden c = do
  listToMaybe <$> runQuery c (userByIdenQuery $ pgString iden)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies with you using `undefined` in the end of your function `getUserByIden`. Because of some complicated type level magic Opaleye is doing under the hood, you need to specify a type for the use of `runQuery`, or simply return the value produced instead of undefined, because undefined throws the top inference algorithm off a little bit:

```
getUserByIden :: String -> PGS.Connection -> IO (Maybe User)
getUserByIden iden c = listToMaybe <$> runQuery c (userByIdenQuery $ pgString iden)
```

I also added a `listToMaybe` call to change the type of the body of the function to match the return type you specified. `runQuery`, when fully applied, returns a value of type `IO [SomeHaskellType]`, not `IO (Maybe SomeHaskellType)`.

Comment: Thanks. Another answer (similar content) was posted before yours, so I've accepted theirs. Thank you for your help!